# Disable ordering for specified amount of time?

Tags: orders

Is there a way to disable ordering in Magento for specified amount of time (e.g. 24 hours between two orders)?

Comment: Are you wanting a global setting or per customer, per ip, per email, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for global setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard setting for this.

It depends on where you want to disable it (not able to add products to cart, deny the possibility to go through checkout or maybe disabling them to place orders).

I think it would be nice to show your customers this kind of information as early as possible, otherwise they will maybe be pissed of when they put all products in the cart, went through the checkout and then are not able to place the order.

1.) Pick an event that suites best: Maybe `checkout_cart_product_add_after` or `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` would maybe be fine to do this

2.) Create an observer to check the customers last order, add your restriction there and either allow/deny it there and show a nice error message to your customer.